# Why does removeEventListener not work on event handlers installed by React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a React component where it will attach a bunch of `li` elements to DOM. And some of them have a click `Eventlistener` to them. I'm trying to disable the eventlistener after the user clicked on those special `li`, I'm using `event.currentTarget.removeEventListener('click', this.handleMouse)` for that, but it's not working. Here are the relevant part of the code:

```jsx
var DisplayList = React.createClass({
  /* ... */
  
  handleMouse: function (event) {
    event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    this.props.changeCounts(-1); 
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener('click', this.handleMouse); //NOT WORKING
  },

  /* ... */

  render: function () {
    var self = this;
    return(
      <div id = "listing-boxes-wrapper">
          {
            this.props.sortedList.map(function(item, index){
              if (self.state.changedHabit.indexOf(item.habitid) > -1) {
                return  <li key={index} style={{backgroundColor: '#ccc'}} className = "text-center" onClick={self.handleMouse}>{item.description} 
                        </li>
              }else{
                return  <li key={index} className =" text-center">{item.description}
                        </li>
              }
            })
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reactjs uses `Function.prototype.bind` to bind the context to the handler (otherwise `this` would be `undefined`).

So what happens under the hood is something like:

```
element.addEventListener('click', this.handleMouse.bind(this));
```

So, as you can see it's another function added to the listener, not the `this.handleMouse`.

So after that - you cannot remove it, since it was not even attached.

The react-way solution would be just to re-render the element once again without the handler so that the react detached the handler itself.

[Relevant](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/80bff5397bf854750dbe7c286f61654ea58938c5/src/isomorphic/classic/class/ReactClass.js#L636) (?) code in react:

```
/**
 * Binds a method to the component.
 *
 * @param {object} component Component whose method is going to be bound.
 * @param {function} method Method to be bound.
 * @return {function} The bound method.
 */
function bindAutoBindMethod(component, method) {
  var boundMethod = method.bind(component);
  if (__DEV__) {
    // stripped as irrelevant
  }
  return boundMethod;
}

/**
 * Binds all auto-bound methods in a component.
 *
 * @param {object} component Component whose method is going to be bound.
 */
function bindAutoBindMethods(component) {
  var pairs = component.__reactAutoBindPairs;
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i += 2) {
    var autoBindKey = pairs[i];
    var method = pairs[i + 1];
    component[autoBindKey] = bindAutoBindMethod(
      component,
      method
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If that's the case I will have to pass in a parameter to that onclick callback function. But I also need the event object that get passed to the callback. `self.handleMouse.bind(self, myParameter)`, how do I receive the event object?? Im using bind so it wouldnt auto run the function until it get clicked. Thanks

Comment: Well, you just don't need that - just re-render the element without a handler and reactjs will detach it for you.

Comment: Im not sure if that is possible in my case. I have made some detail inner working in the original post under ur name, can you take a look? thanks

Comment: I've checked it and I cannot understand it. Re-rendering is definitely possible in every case: that's what reactjs developers are supposed to do, that's what reactjs is designed for.

Comment: my bad I couldnt find a way to find out which li was clicked, so I couldnt trigger a change of state that would lead to a re-render. But I just realize I can get the id of an element with event.currentTarget.id. And now I was able to change the state in handleMouse, which led to the re-rendering. Thanks for the help!!